# how to generate dynamic year in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I want to access data from a rest API using pentaho data integration and save the result into a table.

I am using the following steps:

Generate rows step
Rest Client
JSON input
select values
Table output
The API I want to access take a year as an argument.

My Question is here:

How can I automatically change year in the url (generate row step) so that I can get data of many year at a time. With one year the transformation works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Pentaho Data Integration (PDI), you can dynamically change the year in the URL by using variables and parameters. Here's a general guide on how to achieve this:

Use a Variable for the Year:

Create a variable to hold the year value. In PDI, you can define a variable in the "Variables" tab at the bottom of the PDI window.
Use a Set Variables Step:

Add a "Set Variables" step to your transformation. Configure this step to set the value of the variable to the desired year.
Use the Variable in the Generate Rows Step:

In the "Generate Rows" step, use the variable in the URL. Modify the URL field to include the variable using the ${variable_name} syntax.
Iterate Over Years:

Use a loop or iterate over a list of years to fetch data for multiple years.
For example, if you have a list of years in a text file or table, you can use a "Text File Input" or "Table Input" step to read the list, and then loop through each year using a "Copy Rows to Result" step and a "Block Until Steps Finish" step.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: If you have it working for a year in a transformation, then make sure year is setup as a variable (everywhere where you use for example 2023, replace this by ${year} or something the like)

Then just make a parent transformation with 2 steps. The first is a generate series which creates records with 1 column named year, and then feed that into a transformation step (linked to your succesfull transformation).

In the properties of the transformation step, set it to run for each row (checkmark) and map the column year to the parameter year. And it should work.

That is the easiest way to do it.